# Mercurial: How to ignore multiple heads of a branch when used as ancestor on a closed branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Another git user confused by Mercurial branches here.  I've done something that I can't figure out how to undo and as a result I cannot push my totally unrelated changes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the story, I think:

- I started working on something on *default*.  I realized this was a mistake as it would become a PR, so the next commit I did on a branch *feature1*.  I then submitted a PR on bitbucket.
- I started working on something else, also off of *default*, this time I was certain to use a branch *feature2*, and I did purposely "hg up -r ..." with the revision number *before* my *feature1* commit so as not to include that change.

At this point the history looks something like,

```
                   -- G (default) - H (feature1)
                  /
.. D - F (default)
                  \
                   -- I - J - K (feature2)
```

- My PR was not accepted, so I close *feature1*.
- There has been development on default in the parent repository, so I `hg pull`.  Now it looks something like,

  ```
                     -- G (default) - H (feature1) [my repository, closed]
                    /
  .. D - F (default)--- L (default) [parent repository]
                    \
                     -- I - J - K (feature2) [my repository]
  ```

.. plus lots of changes on other branches that I don't know anything about.

- But I'm happy with *feature2* and I want to make a PR for it, so I try to `hg push --new-branch`, but I get the message,

  abort: push creates new remote head 7a341084eb8a!

Ok, so use `hg glog` and it appears the checksum corresponds with the parent work, i.e. `L` in the diagram above.  Mercurial seems to be complaining that I have a commit on a closed branch with the branch `default` that has not been merged into `default`!  But I don't want it to exist anymore!  However, I don't want to strip it as then it would make reading the old, closed PR impossible.

If I try to push just my own branch, `hg push --new-branch -b feature2`, then I get:

```
abort: push creates new remote head 062efd5d0886!
```

i.e., same problem but with a different head.  This one appears to correspond with the first patch of *feature2*! That is, `I` in my diagram.

This makes no sense.. a *closed* branch is stopping me from pushing the changes on an entirely other branch.  Meanwhile I can't figure out what multiple heads it's even talking about when pushing my *feature2* branch, since there is really only one *feature2*.  The recommendation is to "merge" before pushing, but I can't even figure out here *what* to merge.  I don't want to merge my rejected change on *default*, and when I do `hg merge default` on *feature2*, thinking maybe I need to take into account the latest upstream changes, this merges `G`, from my *closed branch* instead of the upstream head.

So, clearly, I just don't understand Mercurial branches.  In git I would just delete the *feature1* branch and that would be that.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm happy with feature2 and I want to make a PR for it, so I try to hg push --new-branch, but I get the message,
>
> ```
> abort: push creates new remote head 7a341084eb8a!
> ```

At this point, `revision L` is the head of branch `default`, and you are trying to send `revision G`. Revision G is in the `default` branch, so you will create another head. The branch `feature1` was closed, but not the `default` branch in the `revision G`. You can **update to** `revision G`, and **close the branch** there, or **merge** it with `revision L`.

> If I try to push just my own branch, hg push --new-branch -b feature2,
>   then I get:
>
> ```
> abort: push creates new remote head 062efd5d0886!
> ```

If `revision I` is in the `default` branch, you have the same problem as above.

If not, try `hg push -r <rev number of revision I>`.